# SQL Server remote backup query fails "cannot open the backup device"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, workgroup

I am trying to configure my scheduled backups of a MSSQL database to a mapped network drive, which is on a fileserver running Server 2003 Standard.  Query reads like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE XXXX
TO DISK = N'Z:\mssqlbk\XXXX.bak'
WITH CHECKSUM, STATS
```

Error message that is returned:

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'Z:\mssqlbk\xxxx.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Most solutions I find are thinking a permissions error for the SQL Service account (Mine uses an account named SQLBro).  This is a small workgroup network, no AD.  I have tried the following:

- Verified the user account on database server being used by the process during backup with Procmon:  SQLBro
- Created local account on fileserver SQLBro, matching password with account on db server
- Added permissions for SQLBro account on fileserver to the root volume and target folder for backup on fileserver.
- Tried to add the long SQL user from the default backup location to the fileserver, but the name was too long for standard add local user interface (workaround?).
- Tried running service on db server with local system account instead of SQLBro.

Still same error each time.  I am running out of ideas and looking for workarounds now.  Could backing up locally and then running a robocopy or xcopy to the mapped drive be a kludgy way to do this?

Comment: xcopy of the .bak files from the db server's local admin account was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the SQL Server process doesn't know about the drive mapping.  Did you map the drive as the SQL Service account?

I would suggest changing the drive letter path to the UNC path in your backup statement.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation also i had same problem, And finally i came to know that mistake with local path.

Instance is running in an another node and backup files are creating an another node...
path mentioned in plan was `Z:\VOLMNT04-SQLBACKUP\SQLBackup\SA***PD001-S2\TRN`... for this i was  getting same error

```
Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

and i changed the path to `\\SA***PD001-s25\SQLBackup\SA***PD001-S2\TRN` then executed successfully